# How to start android SDK that comes with Android Studio?

Tags: appium, android-sdk-tools

Now it is not possible to download and install Android SDK standalone - the whole Android Studio is must to be installed.
I installed it, and noticed that I have a folder C:\Android\sdk
How can i execute the SDK GUI? 
This file doesn't work - C:\Android\sdk\tools\android.bat 
BTW - i need this in order to setup my environment for Appium. maybe I'm doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to open `Android Studio`, and the from there you can go to `Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager` to access Android SDK.

If you wish to check detailed steps, you can check **Step 2.2** here - [Appium Tutorial](http://www.automationtestinghub.com/appium-tutorial/)

Comment: Thanks Anish, but when i open SDK Manager this way everything is grayed out.. after few searches on google I can tell this is a wide issue for everyone, not only for me...